# Prevent Calendar on Mac from removing old entries

Tags: icloud, macos, calendar

I'm using El Capitan, and I went to my Mac to check my calendar (which is sync'ed to iCloud). I needed to check the details of an appointment I had 3 years ago. I went back, opened that month, and I saw all my entries. And then after a second, they vanished.

Why did this happen, and how can I stop this from happening?

And, can I use Time Machine to retrieve my old Calendar entries?

Comment: Are you connected with iCloud?

Comment: @RushilSrivastava yes

Comment: This is a very weird issue, have you tried restarting the computer? If not try toggling off/on on iCloud Calendar Sync. Apple doesn't 'delete' your calendar records.

Comment: Try to see your events here: https://www.icloud.com/calendar

Comment: @RushilSrivastava Interesting. But in the past were there options (possibly only on iOS) to delete old entries? I will have to see in the morning if those old entries have returned, in which case I may end up closing the question. I just checked on my iPhone (what I'm using to type this) and indeed those old entries are all happily there.

Comment: iOS has the option to Sync back only so far... 2 weeks to 6 months, or all events; but the Mac ought to keep everything. I have calendar entries going back to the year 2000 - my machines have been carefully migrated since then.

Comment: @RushilSrivastava I went to the Calendar today, and the same problem: Events showed and then disappeared. I disabled iCloud calendar and re-enabled it and the events returned. I don't know exactly what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved.

On my iPhone, all the old entries were still there. But restarting the Mac and going to Calendar again, the same thing happened: The old items displayed and disappeared. However, disabling the iCloud calendar and then re-enabling sync for my iCloud calendars appears to have caused the problem to resolve.